# Simple regex replacement using joined string

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the following code:

```
vars=["aaa","bbb","ccc"].join("|");
str="aaa has bbb has ccc"

# attempt ont
result = str.gsub(/+vars+/,"hello")

# attempt two
result = str.gsub("/"+vars+"/","hello")
puts result
```

How do i get the contents of `vars` into a regular expression to replace all instances with hello?

Comment: Did you mean `result = str.gsub(Regexp.new(vars), "hello")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeh i just realized what i did incorrectly thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: better yet, `Regexp.new(Regexp.union(["aaa","bbb","ccc"].map{|s| Regexp.escape(s)}))`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you explain this solution in an answer?

Comment: Regexp literal also handles interpolation so a solution closer to your initial design would be `/#{vars}/`

Comment: @acooluser779da97ads7asd: there's not much to explain, really. The key idea is pointed out by Wiktor (use `Regexp.new`). I then simply used proper methods for building that union expression in a safe manner. Look up those methods in the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Regexp.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeh that was premature i figured it out thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The `escape` is superfluous - `union` takes care of it: `Regexp.union("a+b*c")  #=> /a\+b\*c/`. Or even `Regexp.union(/dogs/, /cats/i)        #=> /(?-mix:dogs)|(?i-mx:cats)/` (from the examples given by the docs.)

Comment: @steenslag: yeah, turns out it is. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is using `Regexp.new` to initialize the regex or using `#{string}` inside `/.../`:

```rb
str.gsub(Regexp.new(vars), "hello")
str.gsub(/#{vars}/, "hello")
```

See [this online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/hJeEEH). *However*, this simply puts the `vars` contents into the regex.

You may create a regex and automatically escape all the special regex metacharacters in the pattern using [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```rb
vars = ["aa+a","bbb","ccc"]
p Regexp.union(vars)
# => /aa\+a|bbb|ccc/
```

If you need to use this alternation inside some longer regex, you can use

```rb
p /LEFT_PART...(?:#{Regexp.union(vars).source})...RIGHT_PART/
# => /LEFT_PART...(?:aa\+a|bbb|ccc)...RIGHT_PART/
```

Note that `Regexp.union(vars).source` will only return the pattern without the modifier group with regex flags set or unset at the beginning (else, it would look like `(?-mix:aa\+a|bbb|ccc)`).